# Wordpress error in reinstalling from backup

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins, transfer, backups

[I got a backup from the server from duplicator plugin and direct
but non of them did not work properly
the direct downloaded backup got more errors even map url to localhost
but the backup from duplicator also give this errors
these are content from plugins like hotel room booking.. etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9sxc.png)

[enter image description here][2]

Comment: Error itself says table already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try with some manual steps which are easy and effective at the same time. Even use database backup tool like wp migrate db (Read more about the plugin - it can have option for database version compatibility option as well.) :) Coding